# Laravel Form posted html values getting encoded

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.6 and have created a basic form. One of my fields which is a textarea,  expects some html code input. For example, I expect the user to enter

```
<img alt="" src="{club_logo_url}" style="float:right;width:100px;padding-right:10px;" />
```

where {club_logo_url} is a place holder which I look for in the backend.

I use Input::get('ticket_template') to get the posted value in the back end and this is what I get

```
<img alt="" src="%7Bclub_logo_url%7D" style="float:right;width:100px;padding-right:10px;" />
```

So how do I get the exact value as posted by the user without embedding the {} characters? thanks

Comment: thanks, but I cannot expect the user to add 2 brackets. I just want to get the same text they post on my server side without any modifications to it. Simple as that.

Comment: _without any modification_ Yeah but injecting `<script>while (9999999--) alert('l337');</script>` is way more than annoying though